# Shopify CLI Themes Native Gems Installation Problem

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to set up a Shopify CLI Themes project. I follewed the steps on https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/getting-started/create

I created a partners account and a development store. I am the store owner.

I use Windows and I had Node, Bundler and Git. So I installed Ruby and checked MSYS2 components.
Then I did

```
npm install -g @shopify/cli @shopify/theme
shopify theme init
cd "my-new-theme"
bundle init
```

and then pasted below code to Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rack', '~> 2.2.4'
gem 'rspec'
```

and then

```
bundle install
git add Gemfile Gemfile.lock
shopify theme dev --store {store-name}
```

But I get this error each time. How can I solve this problem?

```
Error: Command failed with exit code 5: bundle install
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Users/Basar
Bilgisayar/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
D:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in
/usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi,/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ffi,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ffi...
no
checking for whether -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes
checking for whether -pthread is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Users/Basar
Bilgisayar/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230425-8412-oh75ot
sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230425-8412-oh75ot clean

current directory: C:/Users/Basar
Bilgisayar/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230425-8412-oh75ot
sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230425-8412-oh75ot
generating ffi_c-x64-mingw-ucrt.def
/bin/sh: -c: sat─▒r 1: beklenmeyen jeton `(' yak─▒n─▒nda s├╢zdizim hatas─▒
/bin/sh: -c: sat─▒r 1: `mkdir -p "/c/Users/Basar
Bilgisayar/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x64-mingw-ucrt"
""/c/Users/Basar(D)"'
make: *** [libffi.mk:6: "/c/Users/Basar] Error 2

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/Basar
Bilgisayar/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5
for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/Basar
Bilgisayar/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out

  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:119:in `run'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:51:in `block in make'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in `each'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in `make'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:41:in `build'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:187:in `build_extension'
D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:221:in `block in
build_extensions'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:218:in `each'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:218:in `build_extensions'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:843:in `build_extensions'
D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in
`build_extensions'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in `install'
D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in
`do_install'
D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:147:in
`block in worker_pool'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
D:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in
create_threads'

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  listen was resolved to 3.7.1, which depends on
    rb-inotify was resolved to 0.10.1, which depends on
      ffi
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 2.4.10
Using racc 1.6.2
Using ast 2.4.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.2.2
Using liquid 5.4.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.11.2
Using wdm 0.1.1
Using parser 3.2.2.1
Using bugsnag 6.25.2
Using nokogiri 1.14.3 (x64-mingw-ucrt)
Using theme-check 1.14.0
Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
    at makeError (file:///C:/Users/Basar%20Bilgisayar/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@shopify/theme/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:59:11)
    at handlePromise (file:///C:/Users/Basar%20Bilgisayar/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@shopify/theme/node_modules/execa/index.js:119:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async exec (file:///C:/Users/Basar%20Bilgisayar/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@shopify/theme/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/dist/public/node/system.js:54:9)
    at async shopifyBundleInstall (file:///C:/Users/Basar%20Bilgisayar/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@shopify/theme/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/dist/public/node/ruby.js:375:5)
    at async bundleInstallLocalShopifyCLI (file:///C:/Users/Basar%20Bilgisayar/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@shopify/theme/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/dist/public/node/ruby.js:221:5)        
    at async installCLIDependencies (file:///C:/Users/Basar%20Bilgisayar/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@shopify/theme/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/dist/public/node/ruby.js:134:9)
    at async execCLI2 (file:///C:/Users/Basar%20Bilgisayar/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@shopify/theme/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/dist/public/node/ruby.js:32:5)
PS C:\Users\Basar Bilgisayar\Desktop\Projeler\artistic-focus-theme>
```

Comment: I did but this is not the answer what I need right now. Problem is clear as I explained @isherwood

Comment: Your title still isn't a clear, specific _question_. It's a string of keywords and the vague statement that you have a problem. Please see [ask] again and take the very clear advice it offers regarding titles.

Comment: Please comment only if you know the answers or have suggestions on the problem. Do not comment unrelated things. Platform serves on another purpose.